# Fatal error: Class 'XJ_Igallery_Helper_Data' not found in /home/websit12/public_html/pw/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, class, magento, syntax-error, helper

i installed XJ Custom Photo Album manually then after backend in only show 
Fatal error: Class 'XJ_Igallery_Helper_Data' not found in /home/websit12/public_html/pw/app/Mage.php on line 547 message.please give a suggestion for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

comment out the two define function calls in includes/config.php path

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```